# Angular Error: adding dependecy gives $injector:unpr Unknown Provider

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

I decided to add ngInfinitiScroll plugin to my application. Hence i called the file :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{!! asset('/js/ng-infinite-scroll.min.js') !!}"></script>
```

In my events.js file i initiated the module like this:

```
(function(window) {

    // Define the `app` module
    var app = angular.module('stayhyper', ['infinite-scroll']); 

    app.controller('eventController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$http', 'myService',

        function($scope, $rootScope, $http, myService) {

        } // end of main function

    ]); // end of controller

})(window);
```

Then I get the following error:

> **Error: $injector:unpr Unknown Provider**
>
> Unknown provider: myServiceProvider <- myService<- eventController

MyService (this is in a seperate js file which is loaded in the header):

```
app.service('myService', function() {

            this.URL= function() {
               // set the main route of the site
                var subhost = "/"
                if (window.location.host == "localhost") {
                    subhost = "/myapp/public/"
                }

                window.urlRoot = window.location.origin + subhost;//main root of the site
                return window.urlRoot;
            }
            this.APIURL= function() {
               // set the main route of the site
                var subhost = "/api/"
                if (window.location.host == "localhost") {
                    subhost = "/myapp/public/api/"
                }

                window.urlRoot = window.location.origin + subhost;//main root of the site
                return window.urlRoot;
            }


    });
```

Comment: post the code of myService

Comment: Service posted.

Comment: post the html part where you added those references

Comment: are you sure your calling that service.js in your index.html??

Comment: @Sajeetharan: The all the scripts are loaded in the header.

first angular.js,  then mainapp.js(service), then event,js 

All these are successfully called to the html.

Comment: @Sajeetharan if I call var app = angular.module('stayhyper'); like this, i get no error. The moment i add the  ['infinite-scroll'] part, I get the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load the `event.js` initially and then `mainapp.js` , then only the module will be created initially, also make sure you have added the references in html for `infinite-scroll`

So the order will be,

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ngInfiniteScroll/1.2.2/ng-infinite-scroll.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="mainapp.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="event.js"></script>
```

also make sure you are not calling the module again.

Comment: Argument 'eventController' is not a function, got undefined is the error I get then

Comment: Yes, inbox be your email/skype, so I can send the Teamviewer details to you.